# Add columns in Membership Provider table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database-design, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

Can I add custom columns to the Membership provider table? I know it has a bunch of Stored Procedures. But all I want to add is three more fields - FirstName, LastName, CompanyID and link it to the Company table. Please refer to the screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can. Or you can make another table with the extra information in it and link it by UserId.